# How to perform 'OR' operation between several where conditions in LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I am using  an IQueryable to build my query.

```
 IQueryable<PropertyPosts> posts = context.PropertyPosts;
```

After that based on several conditions I am appending **Where** clause into my query,

```
 if (item.ApartmentCondo == 1)
 {
    posts= posts.Where(x => x.name == item.name &&
                            x.PropertyType == PropertyType.ApartmentCondo );

 }
 if (item.House == 1)
 {
  posts= posts.Where(x => x.name == item.name &&
                            x.PropertyType == PropertyType.House );

 }
```

**Note**: There are several other where conditions also.

After that when I perform the following query,

```
 List<PropertyPosts> posts2 = posts.ToList();
```

All the above **where** conditions will be 'AND'ed.

But instead I need the Where conditions to be 'OR'ed.

Which means I need a way to append several Where conditions, but all these conditions should be  performing 'OR' condition between them.

How can I achieve this? Is there an alternative way rather than using '**Where**'?

Answer (score 3):

You can use following [class](https://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/):

```
/// <summary>
/// Enables the efficient, dynamic composition of query predicates.
/// </summary>
public static class PredicateBuilder
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a predicate that evaluates to true.
    /// </summary>
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T>() { return param => true; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a predicate that evaluates to false.
    /// </summary>
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T>() { return param => false; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a predicate expression from the specified lambda expression.
    /// </summary>
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Create<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) { return predicate; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Combines the first predicate with the second using the logical "and".
    /// </summary>
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> AND<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> first, Expression<Func<T, bool>> second)
    {
        return first.Compose(second, Expression.AndAlso);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Combines the first predicate with the second using the logical "or".
    /// </summary>
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> OR<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> first, Expression<Func<T, bool>> second)
    {
        return first.Compose(second, Expression.OrElse);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Negates the predicate.
    /// </summary>
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Not<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
    {
        var negated = Expression.Not(expression.Body);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(negated, expression.Parameters);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Combines the first expression with the second using the specified merge function.
    /// </summary>
    static Expression<T> Compose<T>(this Expression<T> first, Expression<T> second, Func<Expression, Expression, Expression> merge)
    {
        // zip parameters (map from parameters of second to parameters of first)
        var map = first.Parameters
            .Select((f, i) => new { f, s = second.Parameters[i] })
            .ToDictionary(p => p.s, p => p.f);

        // replace parameters in the second lambda expression with the parameters in the first
        var secondBody = ParameterRebinder.ReplaceParameters(map, second.Body);

        // create a merged lambda expression with parameters from the first expression
        return Expression.Lambda<T>(merge(first.Body, secondBody), first.Parameters);
    }

    class ParameterRebinder : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        readonly Dictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression> map;

        ParameterRebinder(Dictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression> map)
        {
            this.map = map ?? new Dictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression>();
        }

        public static Expression ReplaceParameters(Dictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression> map, Expression exp)
        {
            return new ParameterRebinder(map).Visit(exp);
        }

        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression p)
        {
            ParameterExpression replacement;

            if (map.TryGetValue(p, out replacement))
            {
                p = replacement;
            }

            return base.VisitParameter(p);
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it for your case:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<PropertyPosts>();
//predicate = predicate.OR(x=>x.SomeProperties == someValues);
//predicate = predicate.AND(x=>x.SomeOtherProperties == someOtherValues);

if (item.ApartmentCondo == 1)
{
    predicate = predicate.OR(x => x.name == item.name &&
                        x.PropertyType == PropertyType.ApartmentCondo );
}
if (item.House == 1)
{
   predicate = predicate.OR(x => x.name == item.name &&
                        x.PropertyType == PropertyType.House );
}

List<PropertyPosts> posts2 = posts.Where(predicate).ToList();
```

Comment: Sorry @snekkke , I don't know about EF core.

Comment: Sorry. My mistake, it works ok with EF Core. I was using it in the wrong way. I changed the name of the false and true methods because as @MichaelRosendahl said are a little confusing .

Answer (score 2):

Move your `if` conditions inside the Where:

```
posts = posts.Where(x => x.name == item.name && 
                   (    (item.ApartmentCondo == 1 && x.PropertyType == PropertyType.ApartmentCondo)
                     || (item.House == 1          && x.PropertyType == PropertyType.House) );
```

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
posts= posts.Where(x => x.name == item.name &&
                   (
                    (item.ApartmentCondo == 1 && x.PropertyType == PropertyType.ApartmentCondo) || 
                    (item.House == 1 && x.PropertyType == PropertyType.House))
                   );
```

Comment: Can you please show how to build this dynamically as asked in the question?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for a new answer, but I have too little rep to comment.

The True/False works but are a little confusing and also generates multiple starting points. I've modified the code and removed the True<T> and False<T> methods and made a new overload method for Create<T>.

```cs
public static class PredicateBuilder
{
    public const bool TreatEntireExpressionAsAnd = true;
    public const bool TreatEntireExpressionAsOr = false;

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Create<T>(bool value = TreatEntireExpressionAsAnd) { return param => value; }
    ...
```