# Multiple Where clauses in query using EF in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, iqueryable

I have two IQueryable queries:

```
IQueryable<Ad> list1 = db.Ads.Where(x=>x.isModerated == true);
IQueryable<Ad> list2;

if(something == true)
{
    list2 = list1.Where(x=>x.TypeId == 2) 
    // is it going to be the same as query below?
    IQueryable<Ad> list1 = db.Ads.Where(x=>x.isModerated == true && x.TypeId == 2)   
}
```

and what if I would like to get a data using OR (||) operator is the same scenario.

And I believe it is going to be one db call until I want to iterate this query. Right?

Comment: Yes, multiple `Where` clauses are And'ed together.  If you need or logic that has to be in one `Where`.

Comment: See: [How to perform 'OR' operation between several where conditions in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40500424/how-to-perform-or-operation-between-several-where-conditions-in-linq).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> is it going to be the same as query below?

Yes

> and what if I would like to get a data using OR (||) operator is the same scenario.

Its going to be far less resource expensive to do it like:

```
IQueryable<Ad> list1 = db.Ads.Where(x=>x.isModerated);
IQueryable<Ad> list2;

if(something == true)
{
    list2 = list1.Where(x=>x.TypeId == 2) 
}
else 
{
    list2 = db.Ads.Where(x=>x.isModerated  || x.TypeId == 2)  
}
```

But if for some reason you do not want to do it that way you could do it:

```
list2 = list1.Union(db.Ads.Where(x=> x.TypeId == 2))
```

will give you the same result set

Answer (score 1):

As I could notice, you do have a query with a where clause named list1, and if you do have something equal true, you would add another where clause so I would take a leaner, simpler approach I think.

```
IQueryable<Ad> list1 = db.Ads.Where(x => (x.isModerated == true) && (something != true || x.TypeId == 2));

List<Ad> fetchedAds = list1.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list2 = list1.Where(x=>x.TypeId == 2) 
// is it going to be the same as query below?
IQueryable<Ad> list1 = db.Ads.Where(x=>x.isModerated == true && x.TypeId == 2)
```

Yes - it will be the same.

Comment: And yes it will be one db call unless you enumerate through this.